# Laravel 4, how to prevent Eloquent model from handling certain properties?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'my_users';

    // The 'my_users' table does *not* provide this column.
    protected $computedValue;

    public function doSomething() {
        // Anyway, for some reason, i need the property to exist in the model.
        $this->computedValue = 'foo';
    }
}
```

When i do `User::save()`, an error is triggered because Eloquent is trying to `insert into my_users (computedValue) values('foo')`

Actually, i'm unsetting properties before i trigger the save. Is there an alternative way (other than listening the saving event to unset things), like

```
protected $discard = array('computedValue', 'anyOtherFieldNotToMap');
```

?

Answer (score 4):

You can try giving that member variable a default value.

```
protected $computedValue = false;
```

Reference to Laravel Forum [Setting transient properties on Eloquent models without saving to database?](http://laravel.io/forum/02-10-2014-setting-transient-properties-on-eloquent-models-without-saving-to-database)

Seems to have worked for that Poster.

Comment: Thanks, this requires some testing though and sounds weird. I'll check for that pull request too

Comment: yea ... set it and see if you still get the error ... then you will know

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it through converting the entire model to an array then access the property value you need.

take a look at the end of this page

"Appending Values To JSON"
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization